# Every bounded subset of $R^k$ lies in a compact subset of $R^k$

Tags: real-analysis, compactness

> P: Every bounded subset of R$^k$ lies in a compact subset of R$^k$ (p52, Rudin)

How is the above true?
I know that, by theorem, a set $E$ in $R^k$ is closed and bounded if and only if $E$ is compact. We don't know if the subset is closed so I think we can't apply the theorem to conclude P.

Comment: "lies in" means "is contained in".

Comment: Since the set is bounded it must be contained in some closed ball in $\mathbb{R}^{k}$. A closed ball is a compact subset as it is closed and bounded.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $A$ is bounded, then $A\subseteq \overline{B_r(0)}$ for some $r>0$.

***Exercise 1***: Prove or disprove: every closed subset of $\mathbb{R}^k$ is contained in a compact subset of $\mathbb{R}^k$.

***Exercise 2***: Prove that every closed subset of $\mathbb{R}^k$ is the union of countably many compact subsets of $\mathbb{R}^k$. (*Hint*: prove that $\mathbb{R}^k$ is the union of compact subsets of $\mathbb{R}^k$ and note that the intersection of a closed set and a compact set in $\mathbb{R}^k$ is compact.)

I hope this helps! (Also, thanks very much to Ted Shifrin below who pointed out improvements!)

Comment: Thanks @Ted for this suggestion! I definitely agree with you and I've edited my answer.

Comment: Thanks :) Now I feel duty-bound to comment that any set is a union of compact sets, as a point is a compact set. Did you perhaps mean to say a countable union? P.S. Amitesh, are you really 18? Just curious :)

Comment: Thank you very much @Ted for pointing this out! (I was offline so I didn't see your comment until now. I've unfortunately been a little sloppy lately with some of my answers; it's great that people are suggesting improvements!) Yes. :)